# Clear canvas after ctx.arc was clicked

Tags: javascript, canvas

So the objective is to place a circle randomly on the screen, and if the circle was clicked, remove this old circle and make a new circle.

I'm having a problem with removing the old point and making a new one. Instead of removing the old one, it keeps it, makes a new circle and eventually does whatever this is after a bit of clicking:

[image]

This is how my code looks like:

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
function randSpot() {
  var X = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width) + 10;
  var Y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height) + 10;
  ctx.arc(X, Y, 5.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fill();
  document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(e.clientX, e.clientY)) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      randSpot()
    }
  });
}
randSpot()
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You keep `addEventListener('click')` every time you `randSpot()` that can't be right

Comment: then i should removeEventListener after right?

Comment: I would say just `addEventListener` once but you are binding it to the `ctx` so I don't know. But since this is not working for you (the `isPointInPath` part) I would definitely use one event handler to check against distance of click from last known `X` and `Y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to begin a new path

```
ctx.beginPath();
```

I had to modify the code to make it run in the snippet

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";

function randSpot() {
  var X = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width) + 10;
  var Y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height) + 10;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(X, Y, 5.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fill();
}
randSpot()

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // I had to remove the following condition
  // ctx.isPointInPath(e.clientX, e.clientY)
  // because the code didn't wanted to work with the snippet
  // but it's unrelated to the problem
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  randSpot()
});
```

Comment: Even if you don't click on the circle, it replaces with a new circle, it should only replace if you click on the circle.

Comment: I removed that one `if` because it wasn't working here. Unrelated to the problem you had.